# ScrolledComposite does not scroll when focus is inside Text (Mac only)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a simple CTabFolder with ScrolledComposite that hosts Composite with number of Text controls. When there is a focus inside a Text control and I try to scroll the page, it fails on Mac OS, but works fine on Linux and Windows. Is there a known issue with this use case on Macs?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does 'it fails' mean? What happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: On Mac Composite does not scroll when I use mouse wheel for example and have mouse focus inside a Text field. Works fine on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Baz, greg-449 here is MCVE - https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8860827

Comment: This code works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.11.3 using an Apple Wireless Trackpad.

Comment: Ha, I'll have to try this code again in context of the application, because it definitely does not work there. Thanks greg-449.